# Scaling UIWebView to fit full screen in iOS5 and iOS6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I have a problem with scaling the UIWebView. I want that the WebView is running in fullscreen on both versions (iOS5 and iOS6). I had to turn off "use AutoLayout" to get my app running on iOS5 too. My Problem is that my webView is higher than the the iOS5 Screen.

My question:

Is there a way to fit the view for both devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually code for the view to change size based on the screen size.

You can fetch the screen size (specifically height):

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
```

Then you set the size of the UIWebView with these values.

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
```